# Local Vercel serverless CORS issue

Tags: node.js, cors, vite, vercel

I read every single doc and post but no matter what I do I'm getting

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/test1' from origin
'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Vue SPA app with Vite and the following Axios request:

```
await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/test1', {})
```

The `api/test1.js` contains the exact code from [Vercel CORS docs](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-enable-cors) under `Enabling CORS in a single Node.js Serverless Function` except the last line which is `export default allowCors(handler)` in my code.

My `vercel.json`:

```
// vercel.json

{
  "buildCommand": "vite build --mode vercel",
  "devCommand": "vite --mode vercel --port=$PORT",
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I run Vercel with `vercel dev`

I also have a `test2.js`:

```
// api/test2.js

console.log("1");
export default function handler(request, response) {
  console.log("2");
  return response.status(200).json({ text: 'I am a Serverless Function!' });
}
console.log("3");
```

which resulting the same error but interestingly the `2` not get logged in the console.
Here is the debug log for that request:

```
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.193Z] OPTIONS /api/test2
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.194Z] Reading `package.json` file
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.194Z] Reading `vercel.json` file
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.196Z] Locating files /vercelproject
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.197Z] Ignoring .git
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.197Z] Ignoring .gitignore
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.197Z] Ignoring .vercel
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.197Z] Ignoring node_modules
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.234Z] Locating files /vercelproject [38ms]
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.248Z] Using local env: .env
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.252Z] Imported Builder "@vercel/node" from "/pnpm/global/5/.pnpm/@vercel+node@3.0.23/node_modules/@vercel/node"
1
3
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:39.971Z] Proxying to "@vercel/node" dev server (port=50404, pid=67875)
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:40.008Z] Killing builder dev server with PID 67875
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:01:40.008Z] Running shutdown callback for PID 67875
```

Vercel cli version: `33.6.1` (latest)

---

UPDATE 1:

If I change the POST request to a GET one (nothing else) the debug log changes and the 2 get appearing:

```
1
3
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:49:19.067Z] Proxying to "@vercel/node" dev server (port=63950, pid=3861)
2
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:49:19.111Z] Killing builder dev server with PID 3861
> [debug] [2024-03-15T20:49:19.111Z] Running shutdown callback for PID 3861
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an [issue](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/10927) in vercel's repo with this problem.

TLDR:
Problem introduced in vercel version `32.0.2`.
Workarounds:

- use vercel version [`32.0.1`](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/releases/tag/vercel%4032.0.1)
- convert your POST request to GET